# Modify query with sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query

```
SELECT      distinct DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, [Date Time]), 0) as Date
FROM         [Vente A]

union 

SELECT      distinct DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, [Date Time]), 0)
FROM         [Vente B]

UNION 

SELECT      distinct DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, [Date Time]), 0)
FROM           [Budget B]

UNION 

SELECT      distinct DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, [Date Time]), 0)
FROM            [Budget A]
```

I need to select date from Vente A and Vente B 
then select select from budget A and budget B where date is less than the max date from Vente A and Vente B

how can i do it ?

Comment: Please edit your query with sample data and desired results.  Your logic is hard to follow, particularly without any data that explains what you really want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you want this: Pick the max date from the union od Vente A and B. Then show all rows from union of Budget A and B where data is less than the max date selected above.

```
SELECT BudgetDate
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, [Date Time]), 0) AS BudgetDate
  FROM [Budget B]

  UNION

  SELECT DISTINCT DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, [Date Time]), 0)
  FROM [Budget A]
  ) BudgetAB
WHERE BudgetDate < (
    SELECT MAX(DATE)
    FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, [Date Time]), 0) AS DATE
      FROM [Vente A]

      UNION

      SELECT DISTINCT DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, [Date Time]), 0)
      FROM [Vente B]
      ) AS VenteAB
    )
```

or, like this

```
;WITH BudgetAB
AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, [Date Time]), 0) AS BudgetDate
  FROM [Budget B]

  UNION

  SELECT DISTINCT DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, [Date Time]), 0)
  FROM [Budget A]
  )
SELECT BudgetDate
FROM BudgetAB
WHERE BudgetDate < (
    SELECT MAX(DATE)
    FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, [Date Time]), 0) AS DATE
      FROM [Vente A]

      UNION

      SELECT DISTINCT DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, [Date Time]), 0)
      FROM [Vente B]
      ) VenteAB
    )
```